# which a design pattern shoud I choose to do this

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have several options to connect to my host,that is via native API call, webserviecs, COM lib and java lib, it means that if any of a method I use to connect to host fails, I will use another method.So  what is design patterns should I choose to implement this case ?

Ps: In each method to connection, just there are 6 methods: connect(); signin(); sendata(); receivedata(); signout() and disconnect().

Comment: What about Factory or Strategy ? Others could match too, you don't give enough details.

Comment: Have a look at [Chain of Responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern).

Comment: Can I use provider model design patter?

Comment: Each method of connection return different object, so it can not (auto)interchange. what I want is if one method failed, I manually change the config file to use another connection method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the "Chain of Responsibility". It keeps going to the next option until you find the correct one.

Taken from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern#C.23):

> The chain-of-responsibility pattern is a design pattern consisting of
>   a source of command objects and a series of processing objects.
>   Each processing object contains logic that defines the types of
>   command objects that it can handle; the rest are passed to the next
>   processing object in the chain. A mechanism also exists for adding new
>   processing objects to the end of this chain.

Comment: this seem not suit because each method of connection return different object, so it can not (auto)interchange. I want if one method failed, i manully change the config file to use another connection method.

Comment: there were very few data before you edited, so it seemed that chain of responsability could fit, now I think is too messy and that maybe you are creating innecesary objects